# Dotnet Core AWS Lambda For Cognito Post Confirmation Trigger Completion

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I use Cognito User Pools and for a Post Sign Up Confirmation Trigger I am writing a dotnet core lambda to do some followup work. I stared by simple logging out what I get in and do some work from there. Thing is I realised my logging out works but then when the Function should "finish" it fails to do so. It produces the following error - Code: `InvalidLambdaResponseException`, Message: `Unrecognizable lambda output`. Here is my `FunctionHandler`:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
...
public async Task FunctionHandler(JObject input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    context.Logger.LogLine($"INPUT:{input}");
    //Do some work      
}
```

I can only find a [NodeJS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-confirm-tutorials) for Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
            sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, "Congratulations " + event.userName + ", you have been confirmed: ", function(status) {

            // Return to Amazon Cognito
            callback(null, event);
        });
    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        callback(null, event);
    }
};
```

In this example, it's simple - You simple invoke the `callback`, but there is no such callback for the dotnet core handlers.

I have also tried changing the function to simply return a basic string like: `return "OK";`, but it also does not like that and gives me the same error.

How am I suppose to close of this process for the Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You could use;

```
await Task.CompletedTask;
```

check out the examples below: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html

For Cognito Post Confirmation Event;

```
public JObject FunctionHandler(JObject input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"input data: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input)}");
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: i am getting this error "PostConfirmation failed with error Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.version | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 14.."

Answer (score 1):

When I was using `JObject` it was throwing the below error

> PostConfirmation failed with error Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject: The JSON value could not be converted to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken. Path: $.version | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 14..

Previously AWS was using `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer` which uses `Newtonsoft.Json` new version uses `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer` which implements the recent `System.Text.Json` so `JObject` is no longer appropriate and you can replace it with `JsonElement`

```
public async Task<JsonElement> FunctionHandler(JsonElement input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var request = input.GetProperty("request");
    var userAttributes = request.GetProperty("userAttributes");
    string email = userAttributes.GetProperty("email").GetString();

    return input;
}
```